# Why does this POSIXct or ITime loses its format/attribute

Tags: r, data.table

here is my sample data, I do not understand why the `ITime` column loses it's format in the following code using the `data.table` package

```
DT = data.table(x=as.POSIXct(c("2009-02-17 17:29:23.042",
                               "2009-02-17 17:29:25.160")),
                y=c(1L,2L))
DT[,x1:=as.ITime(x)]
DT[,`:=`(last.x=tail(x,1L),last.x1=tail(x1,1L)),by=y]
DT
                         x y       x1     last.x last.x1
1: 2009-02-17 17:29:23.042 1 17:29:23 1234888163   62963
2: 2009-02-17 17:29:25.160 2 17:29:25 1234888165   62965
```

But If `data.table` already knows the format like in the following, It works

```
DT = data.table(x=as.POSIXct(c("2009-02-17 17:29:23.042",
                               "2009-02-17 17:29:25.160")),
                y=c(1L,2L))
DT[,x1:=as.ITime(x)]
DT[,`:=`(last.x=x,last.x1=x1)] #HERE DATA>TABLE KNOWS THE LAST.* FORMAT
DT[,`:=`(last.x=tail(x,1L),last.x1=tail(x1,1L)),by=y]
R) DT
                         x y       x1                  last.x  last.x1
1: 2009-02-17 17:29:23.042 1 17:29:23 2009-02-17 17:29:23.042 17:29:23
2: 2009-02-17 17:29:25.160 2 17:29:25 2009-02-17 17:29:25.160 17:29:25
```

It must be something about how `data.table` assigns, is there a work around ?

**UPDATE** Thanks to Arun this is now fixed

```
R) library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.11  For help type: help("data.table")
R) DT = data.table(x=as.POSIXct(c("2009-02-17 17:29:23.042",
+                                "2009-02-17 17:29:25.160")),
+                 y=c(1L,2L))
R) DT[,x1:=as.ITime(x)]
R) DT[,`:=`(last.x=tail(x,1L),last.x1=tail(x1,1L)),by=y]
R) DT
                         x y       x1                  last.x  last.x1
1: 2009-02-17 17:29:23.042 1 17:29:23 2009-02-17 17:29:23.042 17:29:23
2: 2009-02-17 17:29:25.160 2 17:29:25 2009-02-17 17:29:25.160 17:29:25
```

Comment: Your code is a valid workaround. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @statquant Just checking - can't see it if you did file it. Shall I file this one?

Comment: done (from the ski-lift ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: This has been fixed in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=975):**

> `:=` (assignment by reference) loses `POSIXct` or `ITime` attribute *while grouping* is now fixed, [#2531](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=975&aid=2531&group_id=240). Tests added. Thanks to stat quant for reporting here: 
>        [Why does this POSIXct or ITime loses its format/attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604820/why-does-this-posixct-or-itime-loses-its-format-attribute) and to Paul Murray for reporting here on SO: 
>        [Cannot assign columns as.Date by reference in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996692/cannot-assign-columns-as-date-by-reference-in-data-table)

Please write back if I seem to have overlooked something.

Answer (score 1):

Filed as [bug #2531](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/155), priority updated by Matthew.