# Cannot assign columns as.Date by reference in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm assigning a new column as `Date` or `IDate` while using `by =`. It's creating an integer column, not a `Date` as expected.

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(date = as.IDate(sample(10000:11000, 10), 
                                 origin = "1970-01-01"))
dt[, group := rep(1:2, 5)]
print(dt)

#           date group
#  1: 1997-06-12     1
#  2: 1998-02-19     2
#  3: 1998-04-25     1
#  4: 1998-01-27     2
#  5: 1997-10-29     1
#  6: 1998-05-08     2
#  7: 1999-05-09     1
#  8: 1999-06-26     2
#  9: 1997-11-01     1
# 10: 1997-07-19     2
```

This works:

```
dt[, min.date := min(date)]
print(dt)

#           date group   min.date
#  1: 1997-06-12     1 1997-06-12
#  2: 1998-02-19     2 1997-06-12
#  3: 1998-04-25     1 1997-06-12
#  4: 1998-01-27     2 1997-06-12
#  5: 1997-10-29     1 1997-06-12
#  6: 1998-05-08     2 1997-06-12
#  7: 1999-05-09     1 1997-06-12
#  8: 1999-06-26     2 1997-06-12
#  9: 1997-11-01     1 1997-06-12
# 10: 1997-07-19     2 1997-06-12
```

But here's the problem:

```
dt[, min.group.date := as.IDate(min(date)), by = group]
print(dt)

#           date group   min.date min.group.date
#  1: 1997-06-12     1 1997-06-12          10024
#  2: 1998-02-19     2 1997-06-12          10061
#  3: 1998-04-25     1 1997-06-12          10024
#  4: 1998-01-27     2 1997-06-12          10061
#  5: 1997-10-29     1 1997-06-12          10024
#  6: 1998-05-08     2 1997-06-12          10061
#  7: 1999-05-09     1 1997-06-12          10024
#  8: 1999-06-26     2 1997-06-12          10061
#  9: 1997-11-01     1 1997-06-12          10024
# 10: 1997-07-19     2 1997-06-12          10061
```

`min.group.date` is numeric instead of `Date`.

```
dt[, class(min.group.date)]

# [1] "numeric"
```

If I initialize the column as a `Date` or `IDate`, it works as expected:

```
dt <- data.table(date = as.IDate(sample(10000:11000, 10), origin = "1970-01-01"))
dt[, group := rep(1:2, 5)]

dt[, min.group.date := as.IDate(NA)]
dt[, min.group.date := min(date), by = group]

dt[, class(min.group.date)]
# [1] "IDate" "Date"
```

Comment: This [bug](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2531&group_id=240&atid=975) may be related.

Comment: @statquant – You're right. I just flagged it... (yes, flagged my own question)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this Paul. This is now fixed in *v1.8.11*. [See here:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18927785/559784).

Answer (score 1):

Paul, if all you want is to group by minimum dates, this line will do it:

```
dt[,min(date),by=group]
```

you should see (the dates below obviously differ from yours because of the 'sample' command in your example):

```
   group         V1
1:     1 1997-11-19
2:     2 1997-12-04
```

If you want to see every row you can join the tables:

```
setkey(dt,group) #always good practice
dt_min=dt[,min(date),by=group]
setnames(dt_min,"V1","min.group.Date") #you should NOT use colnames (see help('setnames')
dt[dt_min]


    group       date min.group.Date
 1:     1 1999-01-30     1997-11-19
 2:     1 1999-11-27     1997-11-19
 3:     1 1999-11-11     1997-11-19
 4:     1 1997-11-19     1997-11-19
 5:     1 1999-05-06     1997-11-19
 6:     2 1999-07-11     1997-12-04
 7:     2 1997-12-04     1997-12-04
 8:     2 1998-07-28     1997-12-04
 9:     2 1998-10-23     1997-12-04
10:     2 1998-06-01     1997-12-04
```

Comment: Well, sure, I can think of several different workarounds, but this is turning one elegant line of code, `dt[, min.date := min(date), by = group]` into four. Why doesn't the assignment by reference preserve the date class?

Comment: Paul, remove 'group' from the colname "min.group.date". For example: dt[, min.date := min(date), by = group], will give you the answer.

Comment: That's only true if `min.date` is "initialized" as a `Date` or `IDate`. The name of the column variable has nothing to do with it.